# Query eureka without registering as a service

Tags: java, spring, microservices, netflix, netflix-eureka

I'm building a service X that will use eureka. I use spring boot and spring cloud. I want to check if i configured X correctly (load balancing, service discovery etc). to do it i would like to run X locally and connect/query existing eureka (on company's UAT environment) but without registering X as a new service so no traffic is redirected to my local machine.

is it possible? what configuration is needed to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this property it works for me:

```
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
```

But I also found an example in the eureka documentation:
https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/blob/master/eureka-examples/conf/sample-eureka-client.properties

> note that for a purely client usage (e.g. only used to get information about other services, there is no need for registration. [...]

```
eureka.registration.enabled=false
```